# Is it possible to keep PDF in resources folder and display it in application?

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to show a PDF offline in my application. We keep our image files in drawable and set them to imageview. In the same way is it possible to display PDF keeping it in resources.

Comment: u can save whole pdf in some folder and next time app opens show that pdf in app using some pdf viewer libarary

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Android's [PDFRender](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) Class. You would construct something similar to below then set to `ImageView` via the `YourImageView.setImageBitmap()` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

```
// create a new renderer
PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

// let us just render all pages
final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
   Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

  // say we render for showing on the screen
  page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

  // do stuff with the bitmap

  // close the page
  page.close();
}

// close the renderer
renderer.close();
```